# Why does table come out as NoneType?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, numpy

```
priceData = pd.read_excel(r'...\Downloads\PriceData.xlsx', skiprows=range(1), usecols = 'B:SN', index_col = 0)
priceData = priceData.drop(priceData.index[[0,1]])
priceData.index.names = ['Date']
priceData.index = priceData.index.map(pd.to_datetime)
sortedPrices = priceData.sort_index(ascending=True)

# To adjust all time series data to start from 1990-01-25 to 2018-09-24
for column in sortedPrices.columns:
    if np.isnan(sortedPrices[column].iloc[0]):
        table = sortedPrices.drop([column],axis=1, inplace=True)

table
```

I printed `table` and instead of getting the price table (see below, except that after sorting, the dates should be from oldest to newest), I received this:

```
NoneType
```

Please let me know why `:/`

[image]

Comment: I don't know pandas, but... `inplace=True`?

Comment: You're iterating over the columns, then checking for NaNs, then assigning it, meaning you're reassigning `table` over and over again, while doing `inplace=True`, which acts on the original dataframe and doesn't return a value...I think your loop and assignment may be out of order.

Comment: @G.Anderson I think you might be right... trying to solve that now...

Comment: Thanks everyone, especially @G_Anderson!

Answer (score 0):

`drop` will drop those items from `sortedPrices`, but the function does so in place.  The return value is `None`, rather than a copy of the table.  You need to output the new value of `sortedPrices`, not a separate variable.